# Declare an object in PHP using constant to hold class name (like you can do with variables)?

Tags: php, class, object, constants

This question about syntax/syntax capabilities in PHP.  Take for example, using variables to store class names when declaring objects:

```
$className= 'myClass';
$obj = new $className;
```

I was wondering if there were some way to do the same with constants.  Something along the lines of:

```
define('CLASS_NAME','myClass');
$obj = new {CLASS_NAME};
```

This doesn't work. Obviously I could just use a variable as an intermediary step, but I was mostly just wondering for edification purposes whether this was a formatting issue or if this is just not possible to do directly in this way.

Comment: you can't create an object in this case with `new {CLASS_NAME}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a sensible expression in PHP, as [u_mulder says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735636/417562).

You *can* do it in one line with reflection.

```
$obj = (new ReflectionClass(CLASS_NAME))->newInstance();
```

Any parameters need to go into the [`newInstance`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php) call.

This is a silly idea, not least because having variable behaviour depending on class names in strings probably means bad architecture. Don't do it. But you asked if it is *possible*, and yes, it is.

Comment: I was mostly just curious whether this was possible with constants, not actually using it, but can you back up that statements that you shouldn't use variable functions? It simplifies a lot of coding problems. How else are you going to pass a callback or anonymous function as an argument?

Comment: @ThoraciusAppotite I'm talking about instantiating classes using variables, not calling functions. There are valid use cases for it, but it's relatively rare.

Comment: Example use-case:  You have an interface with many different implementations, and sometimes even the same CLASS_NAME for all implementations where each one lives in its own versioned folder, then you can pass your Factory which version you want and the Factory can return an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

As class name (e.g. `MyClass`) can not be distinguished from constant name `MyClass` - your approach will **not** work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
const CLASS_NAME = '\MyClass';

$className = CLASS_NAME;
$object = new $className;
```

Answer (score 1):

With php >=8.0 you can do the following:

```
final class SomeService
{
    private const HANDLER_CLASS = CustomHandler::class;

    private HandlerInterface $handler;
    
    public function process(): void
    {
        $this->handler = new (self::HANDLER_CLASS)();
    }
}
```